# Private WebContent for a given Role in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to create web contents that can't be visualized by a given role.

For example let's say I have the roles normal-user and plus-user.
I want to create a Web Content that only plus-user's can see.

If I create a WebContent and enable the "View" permissions on it only for the plus-user and display this WebContent in a WebContent display portlet, normal-user's can view it. Is this the expected behaviour? I have disable the default View permission for every role, even the the default guest role.

I must be missing something because I believe this should be a pretty standard and obvious feature.

Thanks

**Update**
Well it seems that I was misunderstanding the way how I could observe the effects of my changes.

It seems that the configuration that I've described works. Although, the web content is hidden only when listing web contents with the Web Content List portlet. If I set individually a Web Content Display portlet to show the private content, any role will be able to see it, even if it hasn't permission. The same happens If I share the URL to the web content.

So my question now is: **Ignoring view permissions is the default behaviour for the Web Content Display portlet?** With Asset Publisher portlet this doesn't happen. The web content is hidden when listing and viewing if the role hasn't view permissions on that content.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct procedure to achieve your purpose:

1. <del>Deny any permission on all web content for guest role and your normal-user role (*Control Panel > Roles > Guest | normal-user > Define Permissions*)</del>
2. Be sure, one by one, that web contents does not have the authorization to be seen by guest and normal-user

However this isn't a best practice since from now in your portal nobody can see any web content unless you assign to him a specific role.

If I can, i suggest you to manage the problem not at this high generic level but at lower specific one, for example you can check the roles of a user directly in a web content template, and only if that user has the appropriate role you show the content.

Another workaround is put the web content in a private page, in this way you will be sure that only site members will see it.

> EDIT

Your problem seemed strange so i started my local portal, its a Liferay 6.2. I only denied view permission for my single web content (image 1) and guest users can't see it (image 2). PS all other permissions are default.

I edited also my original answer because was wrong, the first point its a lie!!

Re-check all your portal permissions because it is easier than we thought! :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the difference between setting the permissions at web content level and at template level? Ignoring the fact that disabling the guest role view permission will prevent anyone, by default, of visualizing a web content. PS: I have updated my question with new info

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to set a role via template, but check the permissions (or more simply if the user has a certain role). In a velocity/freemarker template you can instantiate all the classes available in the portal, so you can use all the methods to read user's roles, loop the roles and if user has your plus-user you show the content otherwise display a error message o something similar.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I want to achieve this behaviour of hidding a content with the default features of Liferay. Without making some custom code changes. At least for now. It's hard for me to believe that this isn't an obvious feature. Although it doesn't solve my question, I'll rate your answer anyway :)

Comment: Edited answer, hope it help.

Comment: After seeing your update, I see two difference with my current situation. I'm using Liferay 5.0.6, don't know if there was an update to the Web Content Display portlet. And in your second image, it's saying that the user can't access the portlet. You prevented guests, or any other role from seeing the portlet in that page. That's fine. But I want them to be able to see the portlet, but not the content being displayed. The error message should be something like "You do not have permissions to access this resource" and not the portlet itself.

Comment: Btw, I've started to look at the source code of Liferay. It seems to me that when listing, the permission is verified (journal_articles/view.jsp). But when viewing the content (journal_content/view.jsp) that permission check isn't checked. But I must confirm this better. Mainly to see if these are the correct files.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues: did your issue get solved? I am facing the same problem. please reply at https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/91816211